# React: input type="checkbox" onChange not triggered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can anyone tell me why **handleChange** isn't triggered when I click any of the checkboxes? The checkboxes is rendered as I want with the expected value, but the click handler is not triggered.

```
 37   var AutocompleteFromCheckboxes = React.createClass({
 38     handleChange: function(e) {
 39       console.log('hi');
 40       return 1;
 41     },
 42     render: function() {
 43       var autocompleteFrom = this.props.autocomplete_from.map(function(value) {
 44         return (
 45           <label for={value}>
 46             <input type="checkbox" name={value} value="{value}"
 47               onChange={this.handleChange}
 48               ref="autocomplete-from"/>
 49             {value}
 50           </label>
 51         );
 52       });
 53       return (
 54         <div className="autocomplete-from">
 55           {autocompleteFrom}
 56         </div>
 57       );
 58     }
 59   });
```

Comment: Note unrelatedly that to get a `for` attribute in HTML, you need to use `htmlFor` in JSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the anonymous function runs with the wrong context: as soon as you don't set it explicitly it's being set to `undefined`.

It means that `this` is `undefined` hence `this.handleChange` should throw an exception (not sure why you haven't checked the console for that. And if you had - why you didn't mention it).

To solve the problem you may pass the context explicitly as the second argument for the `Array.prototype.map` function call:

```
var autocompleteFrom = this.props.autocomplete_from.map(function(value) {
    // ...
}, this);
```

And as soon as you solve this particular issue and ready to dive into the details on how `this` works in JS, please follow this [amazing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127440/251311).

Comment: In addition to @zerkms answer, this is a good reason to use strict mode - if you'd had `'use strict';` at the top of the module containing this component, you'd have got a `this is undefined` error pointing to the `this.handleChange` line.

Comment: Or a good reason to use ES6 with arrow functions, and never worry about `this` scoping again \*brushes es5 off hands\*.  Really though, it's just a compiler flag on jstransform (jsx/reactify/jsx-loader), go ahead and flip it.

Comment: Without `'use strict';`, `this` will be `window`, not undefined.

Comment: @AlexMcMillan yep, but then `this.handleChange` will be undefined. Not much difference (if you know how to use debugger).

Comment: @zerkms big difference... `object.undefinedProperty` will pass `undefined`, making it a silent error - hard to find without going through the code and determining if `object` is what you expected it to be.  `undefined.property` will throw an error, immediately alerting you to the problem.

Comment: @AlexMcMillan it will not be silent - it will be an exception on invocation. With debugger it's obvious instantly - just go up 1-2 levels on the stack.

Comment: @zerkms aah... no.  It *may* produce an exception further down the line, where you're trying to access the returned object and find that it is `undefined`.. but that line itself will *not* produce an exception.

Comment: @AlexMcMillan oh, react silently ignores if the argument is not a valid callable. My apologies then. It surprised me - since that's what I would expect to see (but never experienced since I never tried to pass non existing handler there)

Comment: Thanks guys! :-) Adding `this` as the second argument fixed it. Thanks for the link to more info on `this`, I'll read up on it right away. Also noticed that `'use strict';` would have given me a nice hint **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleChange' of undefined**.